# Как вызвать Win API функцию для создания нового потока в коде С#

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть учебное задание обработать массив в нескольких потоках, причем потоки создавать вручную, даже не посредством объекта `Thread`, а вызывая Win API функцию создания нового потока.

Как мне известно, это функция должна называться как-то вроде `CreateThread()` и принимать штук 7 параметров. Механизм работы примерно такой же как с объектом `Thread`

Вообщем-то меня интересует, что это за функция и как ее вызвать из кода C#.

Comment: Функция называется CreateThread, вот описание https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понял, вызов небезопасного кода WinAPI напрямую, через P/Invoke механизм.

Пример (взят [отсюда](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createthread))

C# сигнатура метода:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private unsafe static extern uint CreateThread(
        uint* lpThreadAttributes,
        uint dwStackSize,
        ThreadStart lpStartAddress,
        uint* lpParameter,
        uint dwCreationFlags,
        out uint lpThreadId);
```

Пример использования:

```
public delegate void StartThread();

unsafe uint StartThread(StartThread ThreadFunc, int StackSize)
    {
        uint a = 0;
        uint* lpThrAtt = &a;
        uint i = 0;
        uint* lpParam = &i;
        uint lpThreadID = 0;

        uint dwHandle = CreateThread(null, (uint)StackSize, ThreadFunc, lpParam, 0, out lpThreadID);
        if (dwHandle == 0) throw new Exception("Unable to create thread!");
        return dwHandle;
    }

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateThread([In] ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
   SecurityAttributes, uint StackSize, System.Threading.ThreadStart StartFunction,
   IntPtr ThreadParameter, uint CreationFlags, out uint ThreadId);
```

Comment: Благодарю. Попробую применить в задаче.

Comment: Тут конечно пример несколько странный - то `System.Threading.ThreadStart`, то собственный `public delegate void StartThread();`